# C standard library and object files

Tags: c

I know that every header file, i.e. `string.h`, should have an object file in which
there is the proper implementation.

I also know that for GCC and glibc there is a `libc.a` or `libc.so` containing object files.

I tried to open `libc.a` to see if I could find, i.e., `string.o` but I didn't find it.

Why? Where can I find for every header the correspondent object file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be implementation dependant. A single `.h` file may correspond to many `.o` or the opposite, you might have many `.h` for a single `.o`

For example, in my `libc.a`, I can see about one module per string function :

```
$ ar t libc.a | grep '^str' | sort
strcasecmp.o
strcasestr.o
strcat.o
strchr.o
strcmp.o
strcoll.o
strcpy.o
strcspn.o
strdup.o
strerror.o
strfmon.o
strftime.o
stringlist.o
strlcat.o
strlcpy.o
strlen.o
strmode.o
strncat.o
strncmp.o
strncpy.o
strndup.o
strnlen.o
strnstr.o
strpbrk.o
strptime.o
strrchr.o
strsep.o
strsignal.o
strspn.o
strstr.o
strtofflags.o
strtoimax.o
strtok.o
strtol.o
strtoll.o
strtonum.o
strtoq.o
strtoul.o
strtoull.o
strtoumax.o
strtouq.o
strxfrm.o
```

Answer (score 0):

well, in my system, `libc.so` shows up in `/lib`

```
[sourav@braodsword temp]$ ls -l /lib/libc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1611564 Mar 10  2010 /lib/libc-2.5.so
```

However, if you're looking for the `source code`, you'll not find that in `.so` file, anyway.

Again, don't expect, *every* header file declaration will have a defferent object file. They are taken together to form the shared library `.so`.